# Starting an Android Activity from a LKM/kernel-space

Tags: java, android, c, linux, linux-kernel

I am developing a security module and i want to start an activity from Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) for authentication of user when he/she tries to access some secure content.

I have worked in Android and I have also worked on Linux desktop butt i don't know that how to start an activity from kernel space in Android?

Comment: Are you able to modify Android source?

Comment: i am not modifying any Android code. I am just making my own module which i insert using **insmod** command like we do in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the 'am' executable(activity manager), found in /system/bin from your lkm.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList
```

The way to do it from inside the lkm is by using the kernel function 'call_usermodehelper'

example:

```
#include <linux/kmod.h>

char *argv[] = { "/system/bin/am", "start", "-a", "android.intent.action.MAIN",  
"-n", "com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList",  NULL};

static char *envp[] =  { 
  "HOME=/", 
  "PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin", NULL };

call_usermodehelper (argv[0], argv, envp, 1);
```

Comment: Note that this will be asynchronous - you'll need to have the Activity which *might* start as a result somehow signal back to the kernel, in a way which can't be spoofed by an imposter.  Usually this would be done by making that Activity part of the system code or having it run under another special UID explicitly defined in the Android kernel and userspace source.